# Adding a little String variable in an Array Causes Syntax Error?

Tags: php, arrays, string, debugging

I'm trying to add a dash `-` and a defined string `$pageurle` right after the `{target}` sothat the url in the href (se below code) is extended with, naturally a dash and the contents of the variable $pageurle

See the existing piece of code into which I would like to inject the dash & variable right after the href:

```
// html for breadcrumbs
var $breadcrumb_templates = array(
    'separator' => '&rarr;',
    'link'      => '<a href="{target}">{name}</a>',
    'wrapper'   => '<div class="breadcrumbs">{items}</div>', 
);
```

Now, when I add the dash and the $pageurle, dreamweaver says i'm doing something wrong and shows an eror. I must be doing something stupid here... but what? Your ideas/code/improvements/possible dives into this matter are much appreciated by me.

[image]

Comment: `'link' => '<a href="{target}' . " " . $pageurle . '">{name}</a>',`   @pst  after . its still no good... error remains in DW :( thanks though for your coment +1  see my updated image

Comment: @pst You should post that as an answer

Comment: @Sam: What does PHP say when you try to actually run it?

Comment: @Phil, but that does not solve the riddle! DW still recognizes an error in that line... Although I am so desparate I would give any suggestion as an answer or not a +1 upvote right now!

Comment: @Sam: Stop staring at your editor and try running it already.

Comment: @Matti @Phil @pst thanks all for posts. Updated image in question. error persists, and after saving and uploading the file, the entire page becomes blanc and only shows `<!doctype html><html lang="nl">`  I think on my server bad php errors are hidden I mus tlogin to plesk to see whats going on... be right back

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, "var" was last used in PHP 4 and has no business being in PHP 5.

Second, class properties cannot run any code (such as the "." in your array()).

Here's the workaround:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $breadcrumb_templates;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->breadcrumb_templates = array(
            'separator' => '&rarr;',
            'link'      => '<a href="{target}">{name}</a>',
            'wrapper'   => '<div class="breadcrumbs">{items}</div>', 
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks very much @Theodore, so now how do I add the `-` and `@pageurle` right after the {target} in there? or would you propose what @Phil said: focus on the constructor and fix stuff right there?

Comment: They most certainly can be initialised with an array, as long as each key/value is a constant or literal

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Phil Brown, unless he changed his answer, he has the need to append a variable to the array at object instantiation.  I showed him how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure it's because class property initialising statements (the `var` gave it away), may only contain constants or literals.

You can't perform anything procedural in the statement.

Best to do this sort of thing in your constructor.

**Edit**

To illustrate

```
class MyClass
{
    public $breadcrumb_templates = array(
        'separator' => '&rarr;',
        'link'      => '<a href="{target}">{name}</a>',
        'wrapper'   => '<div class="breadcrumbs">{items}</div>',         
    );

    public function __construct($pageurle = null)
    {
        if (null !== $pageurle) {
            $this->breadcrumb_templates['link'] =
                sprintf('<a href="{target}-%s">{name}</a>', $pageurle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, `var`, seriously? PHP 4 is dead and buried. Hell, they've even stopped development on 5.2

Comment: With what should the `var` be replaced? Thanks @Phil.

Comment: @Sam A property visibility declaration

Comment: -1 I had to turn my +1 into a -1. I mean... Why do it that way?

Comment: @Theodore It's just an example to illustrate; a) You can use an array of literal values in a property initialising statement, and b) How to manipulate properties in the constructor. It's also an example of starting with a sane default and adding data as more parameters come in. What exactly do you find "not useful" about this answer?

Comment: @Phil Brown Upon reflecting on your question, I realize your answer does have more merit than I originally assumed.  I not only apologize for my presumptions but I reverse my -1 to +1 ;-)